# How to find the number of contiguous subsequences / subarrays whose product can be expressed as difference of squares of 2 random integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math

So,let's suppose the given sequence is {2,1,3,4}. The contiguous subsequences that'd satisfy the question's condition will be {1},{3},{4},{1,3},{1,3,4},{3,4},{2,1,3,4}. Therefore the total number of contiguous subsequences / subarrays are 7.

My Approach: I did a little math and found out that all the numbers which are odd or the numbers which are divisible by 4 will satisfy the question's condition. But when I try to write the program it takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) in worst case as I check for each contiguous subsequence / subarray. Can you help me on how to come up with an optimized approach?

Comment: Do your sequence has a maximum value?

Comment: yes there can be maximum 10^5 values and elements can range in between 0 to 10^9

Comment: This problem seems to be part of an [ongoing contest](https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/SQRDSUB).

Comment: This post should be definitely be taken down until the contest is over.

Comment: This question is a part of https://www.codechef.com/APRIL20B/problems/SQRDSUB , Problem which is under going now.Please avoid asking question from an on-going contest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any number can be represented as a difference of squares if it is odd, or a multiple of 4.
The problem arises when a product has only a single 2 in the prime factorisation. So we can mark them. (i.e all the 2)
Given this we can easily deduce that only what is not a valid subarray for the given condition is

```
[odd, 2, odd, 4*n, odd]
[0,   1,   2,    3,   4]
```

We can see that position 3 will not be in any of the valid subarrays so you can count odds on the left and on the right. 
Number of subarrays where position 1 takes part
the non valid subarrays are [odd, 2], [2, odd], [2], [odd, 2, odd]

Subtracting 15 - 4, Hence the answer is 11.

Do this for every number that has a single two in its prime factorisation.

Answer (score 1):

a number can only be expressed as difference of two squares only if it is odd or if it is divisible by 4.

```
int main()
{

    long long int t, n, i, j, a[100000];

    cin >> t;

    while (t--)
    {

        int c = 0, d = 0;

        long long int sum = 1;

        cin >> n;

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> a[i];

        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            if (a[i] % 2 != 0 || a[i] % 4 == 0)

                d++;
            sum = a[i];
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {

                sum = sum * a[j];

                cout << sum << endl;

                if (sum % 2 != 0 || sum % 4 == 0)

                    c++;
            }

            sum = 1;
        }

        cout << c + d << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```